# Powershell inserting DataTable with SqlBulkCopy, that hold datetime columns

Tags: sql-server, powershell, datetime, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to insert a predefined `DataTable` into a SQL Server database, using `Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy`.

There are different datatypes in the `DataTable`, but the problem is with `Datetime` columns.

Like this one:

```
$Datatable.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'mydate',([datetime])))
```

I have data in the column, and to me it looks fine.

Like if I try `$row.'mydate'.Month` I get the month  I would expect.

So it looks like the datatable is populated with the correct data.

But when I run

```
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($DataTable)
```

I get this error:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column

So this is the first thing I don't get. Why does it say that my datatype is string, when it is datetime. Does `SqlBulkCopy` convert all data to strings ?

I've tried to reproduce the problem directly on the database, and this is what I got.

It has something to do with the formatting of the date. I **can't** insert this `'22-02-2017'`. But I **can** insert this `'02-22-2017'`.

So obviously there is some confusion in the datetime types.

Why does `SqlBulkCopy` try to insert '22' as month instead of day, when clearly data is correct in the datatable.

I'm thinking it might be a culture thing. But the database culture and my workstation culture seems to be aligned. However I did try to change the culture of my Powershell script, like this:

```
function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture)
{
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
}
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')
Set-Culture $culture
```

This does switch the day and month, when I write out the data to the console, but it does not effect the BulkCopy error.

Do you guys have any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

You dataset sequence must be equal to table columns sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp](
[IP] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[USER] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DT] [date] NOT NULL



PS> $DataSet

    IP             User          DT               
    --             ----          --                   
172.16.11.11   SysCopyUser   2017-05-11 15:29:29
```